When calling torchvision.transforms.Normalize and converting to PIL.Image, how are values above 1 handled?
Applying torchvision.Normalize should lead to values below 0 and above 1, and thus below 0 and 255 when switching to integer values.
However, when watching the values, this seems NOT to be the case. How is this handled?
Please find below a code sample to reproduce the issue.
For a bit of context, I am trying to integrate a neural network using onnx into a C++ code, but I fail to reproduce my python results as values below 0 and above 1 are clipped.
from PIL import Image
from torchvision import transforms




def make_transforms(normalize: bool = True) -> transforms.Compose:    
    results = [
        transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
    ]

    if normalize:
        results.append(transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]))

    return transforms.Compose(results)


def main() -> float:

    resize_a_white_image_without_normalization() # works as expected

    resize_a_white_image_WITH_normalization() # how are value > 255 handled???


def resize_a_white_image_WITH_normalization():
    
    # given a given image 
    white = (255, 255, 255)
    white_img = Image.new("RGB", (300, 300), white)

    # when resizing the image, and normalizing it
    resized_img = make_transforms(normalize=True)(white_img)
    resized_img_pil = transforms.ToPILImage()(resized_img)

    # expected normalized value 
    normalized_val = [(1.0 - 0.485) / 0.229, (1.0 - 0.456) / 0.224, (1 - 0.406) / 0.225]
    normalized_val_int = [int(i * 255) for i in normalized_val]

    print(normalized_val) # [2.2489082969432315, 2.428571428571429, 2.6399999999999997] > 1 ??
    print(normalized_val_int)                                   # [573, 619, 673] > 255??
    print([between_0_and_255(i) for i in normalized_val_int])   # [63, 109, 163]
    print(np.array(resized_img_pil)[0,0])   # [ 61 107 161] ???? still different from above!


def resize_a_white_image_without_normalization() -> float:

    # given a given image 
    white = (255, 255, 255)
    white_img = Image.new("RGB", (300, 300), white)


    # when resizing the image, but not normalizing it, 
    resized_img = make_transforms(normalize=False)(white_img)
    # then all pixels should remain white
    assert (np.array(resized_img) == np.ones_like(np.array(resized_img))).all()



def between_0_and_255(value: int):
    return value % 255


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


I don't understand your first sentence Applying torchvision.Normalize should lead to values below 0 and above 1, and thus below 0 and 255 when switching to integer values.. Is your expectation that you should only end up with values between 0 and 1? Normalization performs the operation input[channel] - mean[channel]) / std[channel] why should there be a restriction on the range of the output data without additional clipping?

@FlyingTeller I understand there is no restriction when calling Normalize.
However, when plotting print(np.array(resized_img_pil)[0,0], the values have been clipped.
Was that done by PIL?

Ah, I see. yes, there is clipping because you don't get a flaot PIL image (as you might have expected) and because of an error in your between_0_and_255 function, you get different results in normalized_val_int  and np.array(resized_img_pil)[0,0] (see answer)

There is clipping because you have an 8bit PIL image
Looking at the documentation of ToPILImage, we can see that different PIL image modes are selected depending on the tensor, in your case:

If the input has 3 channels, the mode is assumed to be RGB.

And from the PIL documentation:

RGB (3x8-bit pixels, true color)

So your tensor is automatically converted to an image with pixel values ranging from 0..255 (8 bit). So values are clipped when they are converted to a PIL image
You have an error in your own clipping function
def between_0_and_255(value: int):
    return value % 255

should be
def between_0_and_255(value: int):
    return value % 256

With that, the output becomes
[2.2489082969432315, 2.428571428571429, 2.6399999999999997]
[573, 619, 673]
[61, 107, 161]
[ 61 107 161]

